# Android Device Monitor doesn't diplay files

Tags: android, android-studio

By android device monitor I couldn't find any files within my emulator android 7 Nougat.

It's display empty File Explorer tap even after select device.

It's only accessible by terminal by `adb shell`

```
$ adb shell
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
generic_x86:/ $ ls
ls: ./ueventd.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./ueventd.ranchu.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./ueventd.goldfish.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./service_contexts: Permission denied
ls: ./sepolicy: Permission denied
ls: ./selinux_version: Permission denied
ls: ./seapp_contexts: Permission denied
ls: ./init.zygote32.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.usb.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.usb.configfs.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.ranchu.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.goldfish.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.environ.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.ranchu: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.goldfish: Permission denied
ls: ./file_contexts.bin: Permission denied
ls: ./default.prop: Permission denied
acct  charger d    dev mnt proc              root sdcard  sys    vendor 
cache config  data etc oem property_contexts sbin storage system
```

Pleas guide to be accessible by android device monitor.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

android studio: 2.2.2

Android Device Monitor : 25.2.2

Comment: This is a known issue, reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226984) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225049).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks you, I have downgrade to previous version and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$ adb shell
generic_x86:/ $ su
generic_x86:/ $ ls
```

i,e `switch` to `root` **user** it works

Comment: This is true, but only goes so far. I was able to see all the files, but still unable to extract files off.